# how to config color when i use iterm2 ssh linux server

Tags: ssh, iterm

I use Mac 
and use iterm2 ssh login linux Server
.
but when exec ls 
the terminal is Black and White
how to config then like  mac colors [image: the color]

Answer (score 2):

The default `TERM` type iTerm reports is `xterm` and that should be sufficient from your Mac's end of things to see colours. The problem is there are two things in play here: your local iTerm terminal and the *remote* machine and it's shell configuration. If you haven't setup your shell to show colour, it doesn't matter what your iTerm is reporting for `TERM`.

It sounds like the problem is on the remote end and that you haven't configured `ls` on your Linux system to output colours.

Try setting [LS_COLORS](http://blog.twistedcode.org/2008/04/lscolors-explained.html) in your environment after you `ssh` in to your Linux machine. Here is one way to do it:

```
export LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32'
```

That should give you a fairly good chance of ensuring you see colours when you run `ls` on any directory. If you like the settings, make them permanent by adding that line to your `~/.bash_profile` file on the Linux machine.

You can also use the newer, more generic, `COLORS` environment variable and point it to the `/etc/DIR_COLORS` file that should exist on most modern Linux installations. More tools will key off this than just `ls` so you'll see colour in tools like `grep` too. Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export COLORS=/etc/DIR_COLORS
```

to add colours to more tools.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `Report Terminal Type` value to

```
xterm-color
```